# Grab the url out of a Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Here is an example of the Values in a cell which has the  Image URL:

Product Image ID: 77545, Product Image File: PLC-237-GOLD__81949.jpg, Product Image Path: m/684/PLC-237-GOLD__81949.jpg, Product Image URL: https://www.clarkbetty.com/product_images/m/684/PLC-237-GOLD__81949.jpg, Product Image Description: PLC Lighting Mini Pendants 1 Light Halogen 12v. 50W in Satin Nickel 237 GOLD, Product Image Is Thumbnail: 1, Product Image Index: 0

Is there a way to only show from Product Image URL to the comma at the end of the url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that your URL always begins with `http`.  I assumed that your entire text was in one cell.

I used a combination of the `MID` and `FIND` functions to extract the image URL.  Just paste the following formula into the cell in which you want the URL to be.  This formula assumes the text containing the URL that needs to be extracted is in cell A1.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("http",A1),FIND(", ",A1,FIND("http",A1))-FIND("http",A1))
```

So you will want to change A1 to reference the cell that contains the product information.